# How do I get array format instead of object array returned?

Tags: laravel

I have Laravel 6 code below displays the array with the object format. So I like to display instead of object-based array, just array as I have mentioned below.

```
 $ins_affiliations =   DB::table('ins_affiliations as af')
                ->select('af.id','af.name')               
                ->where(['af.ins_category_id' => $ins_category_type[0]->category_id])
                ->get()->toArray();
```

my code shows

```
  Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => NSDC
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => NCVT
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 14
            [name] => AICTE
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [name] => Others
        )

)
```

what I need

```
Array
(    
    [12] => NSDC
    [5] => NCVT
    [8] => AICTE
    [11] => Others   
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need json_decode

Comment: You can use `pluck('name', 'id')` instead `get()` to execute your query

Comment: @sta json_decode does not work as I expected

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `->toArray()` when you retrieve data and then use mapWithKeys which is collection method

```
$ins_affiliations->mapWithKeys(function ($item) { return [$item->id => $item->name]; })
```

Then you can use `->all()` if you want to get plain array